# Sending sms using C# over bluetooth

Tags: c#, bluetooth

Can I send sms messages to an android device from .net C# application via bluetooth  if it is yes then please guide me how to do it?

regards

Comment: SMS messages are not transmitted via bluetooth but over the GSM network. If you want to transmit a text message via bluetooth that's another story

Answer (score 0):

Gammu/Wammu is one of the most popular libraries there, that support communicationg to lots of different phones over various protocols including Bluetooth.

You can use it to transmit SMS over bluetooth to your phone (depending on the model - see http://wammu.eu/phones/), to send the SMS.
You can also read SMS from your phone using it if required.

libGammu has C library (http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/c/), but I am not sure you can execute C code directly from C#

Hopefully it gives you at least a nod in the right direction.